# C# - compile xml schema into DLL?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010

ProjectA.csproj contains an XSD schema defined thus:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="ItaXmlConfigFileSchemaV1"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/ItaXmlConfigFileSchemaV1.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ItaXmlConfigFileSchemaV1.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/ItaXmlConfigFileSchemaV1.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"               
    xmlns:r="http://tempuri.org/ItaXmlConfigFileSchemaV1.xsd"
>
...schema definitions...
</xs:schema>
```

ProjectA will be compiled into ProjectA.dll, with ItaXmlConfigFileSchemaV1.xsd included as an Embedded Resource.

Then, I create ProjectB.csproj, and in it I include an XMLFile1.xml with the following header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<utilityConfigData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ItaXmlConfigFileSchemaV1.xsd">

</utilityConfigData>
```

ProjectB references ProjectA.dll.

When I add ProjectA.csproj to the ProjectB solution, and open XMLFile1 in the XML editor, Visual Studio 2010 makes all the nice autocompletion/validation stuff available to me in the XML editor for XMLFile1.xml.

However, when ProjectB references the DLL without the project source is NOT loaded, the XML editor doesn't offer any autocompletion or validation based on the schema.

Is there any way to make these features available using just the reference to the DLL?

Comment: You can point to the schema via properties I believe when you have an xml file selected. Then you will have the intellisense. I don't think you can do it just by referencing a dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is. VS needs access to the schema via a file (or URL) in order to load it. In the case where you have project references, VS has the file readily available so you don't have to do anything special. I've found a ton of reasons why it makes sense to have XML schemas exported as plain files as a part of my build process. You may want to do that.